# Validate existing element in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    router.post('/', verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
        const { jobCode, jobName } = req.body
        //Validation for missing information
        if (!jobCode || !jobName) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Please fill all the information!'
            })
        }
        //Communicate with database
        try {
            //[VID]: Existing element
            const job = await Job.findOne({ jobName })
            if (job) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'This job is existed'
                })
            }
            //Passing all validation
            const newJob = new Job({
                jobCode,
                jobName
            })
            await newJob.save()
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Create new job successfully!',
                job: newJob
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: ' Internal server error'
            })
        }
    })
```

This is my code to validate that to find the jobName in database and if it is existed, server will give a message 'This job is existed'.
However, I have jobCode to check existance. So how can I add jobCode to check existence like jobName?

Comment: You mean you want to use both jobName and jobCode in findOne()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have 2 ways for u

```html
//Name
         const jobName = await Job.findOne({ jobName })
            if (jobName ) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'This job is existed'
                })
            }
//Code
       const jobCode = await Job.findOne({ jobCode })
                if (jobCode ) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'This job is existed'
                    })
                }
```

**Or**

```js
  const job = await Job.findOne({ $or: [{ jobCode }, { jobName }]});
              if (job) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'This job is existed'
                    })
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your support  I tried it and succeeded

Comment: Happy to help :))))))

Answer (score 2):

jobCode **AND** jobName:

```
const job = await Job.findOne({ jobCode, jobName })
```

jobCode **OR** jobName:

```
const job = await Job.findOne({ $or: [{ jobCode }, { jobName }]});
```

Comment: i tried doing with the OR keyword and succeed  Thanks for supporting

Comment: @LXT Happy to help :) Btw you can mark this as the correct answer